# Template only has access to ID's of "foreign" table

Tags: php, cakephp, controller, associations

I have been following the [example](http://%20https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/cms/tags-and-users.html) on the cakephp website and modifying so it "works" for my project.

I have a table with a column that is a foreign key to another table, but my template only gets filled with the ID's and not the other columns of the (foreign) table. How do I get access to the "categorieen.type" in my template view?

[image]

```
+----------------------------------+
|           PRODUCTEN              | 
+----------------------------------+
| productenid  (PK)                | 
| categorie    (FK)                | 
+----------------------------------+

+----------------------------------+
|           CATEGORIEEN            |
+----------------------------------+
| categorieid  (PK)                | 
| type                             | 
+----------------------------------+
```

**ProductenTable**

```
class ProductenTable extends Table {

    public function initialize(array $config){
        $this->belongsTo('Categorieen');
        $this->addBehavior('Timestamp');
    }
    ...
}
```

**ProductenController**

```
public function add() {
        $product = $this->Producten->newEntity();
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $product = $this->Producten->patchEntity($product, $this->request->getData());

            if ($this->Producten->save($product)) {
                $this->Flash->success(__('Your product has been saved.'));
                return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
            }
            $this->Flash->error(__('Unable to add your product.'));
        }

        $categorieen = $this->Producten->Categorieen->find('list');

        $this->set('product', $product);
        $this->set('categorieen', $categorieen);
    }
```

**add.ctp**

```
echo $this->Form->control('categorieen', ['options' => $categorieen]);
```

Comment: The important code here is not the add function, but the view (and maybe index, depending on your requirements). Nevertheless, it seems clear that you are not `contain`ing the associated model in the controller, or referencing the associated data in the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to change my **add()** to:

```
public function add() {
        $product = $this->Producten->newEntity();
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $product = $this->Producten->patchEntity($product, $this->request->getData());

            if ($this->Producten->save($product)) {
                $this->Flash->success(__('Your product has been saved.'));
                return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
            }
            $this->Flash->error(__('Unable to add your product.'));
        }

        $categorieen = $this->Producten->Categorieen->find('list', -----> CHANGED
            ['keyField' => 'categorieid', 'valueField' => 'type']
        );

        $this->set('product', $product);
        $this->set('categorieen', $categorieen);
    }
```

and my **edit.ctp** to:

```
echo $this->Form->control('categorie', ['options' => $categorieen]);
```